# issue transforming Python dictionary of one-itemed list to dictionary of floats

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with one-itemed lists as values. How can I transform them simply into a Dictionary of floats?

I've tried this way, but can't get it to work:

```
dict = {a:[1.25], b:[3.35], c:[3.24]}
for lst in dict.values():
    lst = lst[0]
```

The dictionary just stays the same, but I'd like it to be:
    dict = {a: 1.25, b: 3.35, c: 3.24}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're really close!

```
for k in dict:
    dict[k] = dict[k][0]
```

Also, since `dict` is a built-in class name, you should avoid using it as a variable.